# Adding items (table rows) jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add more rows into a TD item. So, when i click a link, all TD would get an extra TR.

```
<td>
    <tr>Test</tr>
    <tr>Test</tr>
    <tr>Test</tr>
</td>

<td>
    <tr>Test</tr>
    <tr>Test</tr>
    <tr>Test</tr>
</td>

<td>
    <tr>Test</tr>
    <tr>Test</tr>
    <tr>Test</tr>
</td>
```

I've been trying with this,

```
$('#add_rows').click(function()
{
    $("td").append("<tr>Test</tr>");
});
```

But it won't work... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your basic HTML knowledge is wrong. <TD> tags are contained by a <TR> not the other way around.

Comment: link is not added in the sample code, no need as alert etc works. TD or TR one way or another, css takes care of how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure is incorrect. `<tr>` are `T`able `R`ows, so, they have `<td>` (`T`able `D`ata) items. Your selector expression is correct, but as I said, your structure is incorrect, so your code not works. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/h6K66/

So, you just need to invert your structure.

Comment: Yes, if i have an alert, it shows.

    $('#add_rows').click(function()
    {
        $("tr").append("<td>Test</td>");
        alert('test');
    });

Comment: As I said, your problem is your table structure. Change it to the correct way (`<td>` inside `<tr>`) and your code will work.